# how to clone private github repo on insecure server (without exposing your password)?

Tags: git, github

I need to deploy an app on a client server. They have access to the private repo, but not to my whole github account. How can I clone the repo without exposing my github login to this unknown server?

Comment: If they have access to the private repo, why can't they clone it? What is the problem here? Could you edit to clarify the configuration, what rights the client has, and what the problem is?

Comment: @sleske because deploying it is part of my work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to suggest using a SSH key, but that would give access to your whole set of repos. Instead, you should use a [deploy key](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys), which is a SSH key for an individual repo.

> Pros
>
> - Anyone with access to the repository and server has the ability to deploy the project.
> - Users don't have to change their local SSH settings.
> - Deploy keys are read-only by default, but you can give them write access when adding them to a repository.
>
> Cons
>
> - Deploy keys only grant access to a single repository. More complex projects may have many repositories to pull to the same server.
> - Deploy keys are usually not protected by a passphrase, making the key easily accessible if the server is compromised.